# Is it worth to buy jQuery 1.4 books?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it worth to buy jQuery 1.4 books now that 1.5 is out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think it's worth it to buy a book for jQuery at all. You can learn anything you need to just by checking the [Docs/API](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) section and asking questions on here. For anything else you need, well, google is full of examples.

Although, I guess that does assume some knowledge of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I use stackoverflow as a jQuery book. Everyone answers questions about jQuery no matter what they are. Why spend money.

Answer (score 2):

This question is actually pretty programming-language independent. Whether it's ever worth buying books to learn a programming language depends on a number of things:

1. **How good are the online tutorials?** Note that "documentation" is not the same as "tutorials"; sure, it's very useful to know exactly how the `deferred.isResolved()` function works, but if you have no idea how that would be used in a program, you may never even know to use that function.
2. **Do you mind paying for a bunch of chapters that aren't relevant/don't help you fully?** This will almost always happen when you buy a book... the material will be more expansive (or less extensive) than you need. Since you're paying for it, consider this cost.
3. **Do you like learning from books?** Many people would prefer to learn from online tutorials, and just as many like learning from books. This is mostly a subjective thing, except for one fact, which is:
4. **Do you need the most up-to-date information?** As it takes a lot of time to write the book and get it to market, books will very often be significantly behind in terms of features of the language they're teaching, which means that books commonly are missing a lot of features.

In the end, it's mostly subjective, so we really can't answer this question for you. If you're really on the fence, get something out of a local library, or use a resource like [paperbackswap](http://www.paperbackswap.com/index.php) to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a lot of 1.4 is in 1.5, but it's  your decision.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, no. http://docs.jquery.com covers the entire API, and a simple Google-search:

```
whatever jQuery
```

Provides you with good resources, almost always on the first hit.
Additionally, new features and fixes are constantly being implemented by the team, so a 1.4 or even a 1.5 book will quickly be outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I bought jQuery In Action over a year ago, which is all based on jQuery 1.2.  I still find it useful today.  I'm confident a 1.4 book will be very useful for a while yet.  Just keep in mind that there are a few new things not in the book.  Learn them well and the 1.4 book has you covered.